# simple html dom and parsing table

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have to parse 2 kind of table
one is this

http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/f12-13/ ("Classifica Generale")

and the other two table are here
http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/f12-13/formazioni?id=30339&g=4

how can i extract this data to an array?

for the first table i wrote this code but I really don't know what I'm doing

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/f12-13/classifica'); 

$tabClassifica = $html->find('table#classifica tr');

foreach($tabClassifica as $n) {
    $team=$n->find('td',0)->outertext;
    $arrayTeams[] = array('teamname' => $team);
}

?>
<pre>
<? print_r($arrayTeams); ?>
</pre>
```

I've to get this Array structure

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [TeamName] => A.C. Tua
        [Pt.] => 9
        [G] => 4
        [V] => 3
        [N] => 0
        [P] => 1
        [G+] => 8
        [G-] => 5
        [Somma Punti] =>  293,50           
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [TeamName] =>  Ehi Team   
        [Pt.] => 7
        [G] => 4
        [V] => 2
        [N] => 1
        [P] => 1
        [G+] => 5
        [G-] => 5
        [Somma Punti] =>  279,50     
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [TeamName] =>  Brontolo
```

Could someone guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to achieve what you want.

Here is an example code:

```
include('phpQuery-onefile.php');

$content = file_get_contents('http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/f12-13/');
$html = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($content);

$table = $html->find('#classifica tbody');
$general_ranking = array();
$i=0;
foreach($table->children('tr') as $tr){
    /**
     * @var DOMElement $tr
     */
    $getTd = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach($getTd as $td){
        /**
         * @var DOMElement $td
         */
        $general_ranking['tr_'.$i][] = trim($td->textContent);
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

This should display something similar to:

```
array (size=6)
  'tr_0' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'A.C. Tua' (length=8)
      1 => string '9' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '3' (length=1)
      4 => string '0' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '293,50' (length=6)
  'tr_1' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'Ehi Team' (length=8)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '2' (length=1)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '279,50' (length=6)
  'tr_2' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'Brontolo' (length=8)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '2' (length=1)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '274,50' (length=6)
  'tr_3' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'milanelcuore' (length=12)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '2' (length=1)
      4 => string '0' (length=1)
      5 => string '2' (length=1)
      6 => string '281,00' (length=6)
  'tr_4' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'LONGOBARDA' (length=10)
      1 => string '5' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
      4 => string '2' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '254,50' (length=6)
  'tr_5' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string 'i puffi' (length=7)
      1 => string '0' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '0' (length=1)
      4 => string '0' (length=1)
      5 => string '4' (length=1)
      6 => string '258,00' (length=6)
```

---

Edit:
After answering I got interested in `simple_html_dom` so I decided to try it out.
The coding style is a little bit easier than `PHPQuery` but it's not that stable I think.
Anyway, here is the code you need to get it working:

```
include('simple_html_dom/simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://leghe.fantagazzetta.com/f12-13/classifica');

$tabClassifica = $html->find('table#classifica tr');

foreach($tabClassifica as $n) {
    /**
     * @var simple_html_dom_node $n;
     */
    $tds = $n->find('td');

    // Don't allow empty records.
    $team = trim(strip_tags($tds[0]->innertext));
    if($team == "" || $team == "&nbsp;") continue;

    $arrayTeams[] = array(
        'TeamName' => $team,
        'Pt.' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[1]->innertext)),
        'G' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[2]->innertext)),
        'V' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[3]->innertext)),
        'N' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[4]->innertext)),
        'P' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[5]->innertext)),
        'G+' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[6]->innertext)),
        'G-' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[7]->innertext)),
        'Somma Punti' =>  trim(strip_tags($tds[8]->innertext)),
    );
}
```